# OWL: can is-part-of relation be defined by universal restriction?

Tags: owl

In the African Wildlife Ontology example in the paper *[Web Ontology Language: OWL](https://www.cs.vu.nl/~frankh/postscript/OntoHandbook03OWL.pdf)*, Grigoris Antoniou and Frank van Harmelen write the following code to represent the fact that branches are parts of trees and leaves parts of branches:

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="branch">
    <rdfs:comment>Branches are parts of trees </rdfs:comment> 
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#is-part-of"/> 
            <ow:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#tree"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
<owl:Class rdf:ID="leaf">
    <rdfs:comment>Leaves are parts of branches</rdfs:comment> 
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#is-part-of"/> 
            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#branch"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```

This says that every branch either does not participate as a predecessor to any is-part-of relation, or is the predecessor of one or more is-part-of relations, the successors of which are always trees. Similarly the second part says that every leaf either does not participate as a predecessor to any is-part-of relation, or is the predecessor of one or more is-part-of relations, the successors of which are always branches.

The problem is that they then write:

```
<owl:TransitiveProperty rdf:ID="is-part-of"/>
```

Obviously an is-part-of relation has to be transitive (after all if a finger is part of a hand and the hand is part of the body, then the finger is necessarily part of the body), but in our case it means that a leaf can also be part of a tree (by transitivity).

But transitivity contradicts the fact that in all is-part-of relations with a leaf as predecessors, successors are necessarily branches (and hence a leaf can never be part of a tree).

I can hardly imagine these people—who are among the founders of OWL—to do such a trivial mistake, so obviously there is something I'm missing, could you please tell me what?

PS. I opened the ontology with Protégé, when I define is-part-of as being transitive the reasoner says that the ontology is inconsistent, when I remove the transitivity property it becomes consistent again… I'm naïvely inclined to believe that there is an error in the Antoniou & van Harmelen code.

Comment: They also said that suproperty of a transitive property is also transitive... You read the chapter from the 1nd edition of "Handbook on Ontologies"; read the 2nd edition instead.

Comment: + https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.09519